# How to call recursive when data connected each other in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, algorithm

How to get node by node relation in between?

For an example, I want to search node A during node Z. For a while my data something like this?

I have data in DB such of this:
[image]
so on and so on.

This is full image that I have.
[image: full illustration]

My goal is to show a list of possible paths from A to Z. Can anybody can help me and show me the script in nodejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, siteFrom: "A", siteTo: "B" },
  { id: 2, siteFrom: "B", siteTo: "K" },
  { id: 3, siteFrom: "B", siteTo: "F" },
  { id: 4, siteFrom: "F", siteTo: "J" },
  { id: 5, siteFrom: "J", siteTo: "K" },
  { id: 6, siteFrom: "K", siteTo: "Z" },
];

// Create a graph as an adjacency list
const graph = {};
data.forEach((edge) => {
  const { siteFrom, siteTo } = edge;
  if (!graph[siteFrom]) {
    graph[siteFrom] = [];
  }
  graph[siteFrom].push(siteTo);
});

// Define a DFS function to find all paths
function findAllPathsDFS(
  graph,
  currentNode,
  targetNode,
  visitedNodes,
  currentPath,
  allPaths
) {
  if (currentNode === targetNode) {
    allPaths.push([...currentPath, currentNode]);
    return;
  }
  if (!visitedNodes.has(currentNode)) {
    visitedNodes.add(currentNode);
    for (const neighbor of graph[currentNode] || []) {
      findAllPathsDFS(
        graph,
        neighbor,
        targetNode,
        visitedNodes,
        [...currentPath, currentNode],
        allPaths
      );
    }
    visitedNodes.delete(currentNode);
  }
}

// Find all paths from 'A' to 'Z'
const startNode = "A";
const endNode = "Z";
const visited = new Set();
const allPaths = [];

findAllPathsDFS(graph, startNode, endNode, visited, [], allPaths);

if (allPaths.length > 0) {
  console.log(`All paths from ${startNode} to ${endNode}:`);
  allPaths.forEach((path) => {
    console.log(path.join(" -> "));
  });
} else {
  console.log(`No paths found from ${startNode} to ${endNode}.`);
}
```

Updated code!!